# Torchlight - How do you feed fish to yourself?

Tags: torchlight

How do you feed fish to yourself in Torchlight? I know how to do feed it to my pet but not myself.

Comment: Thank you too for the wiki. I didn't know that Torchlight was so popular that there was a wiki on it. @JavadocMD @Nick_T

Comment: there is certain rare fish for humans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most common [fish](http://www.runicfollower.com/wiki/torchlight/Fish) are for pet consumption.

Other loot to be had from fishing holes includes random armor, health/mana food (essentially pots), and those that give various defensive buffs (elemental resistances, armor, knockback resist, etc).

Comment: I believe there are a few exceptions to this such as the GrueFish, but simply right clicking those will feed it to yourself.  The GrueFish actually is listed as a Potion type item and show on the Items tab instead of the Fish tab.

Answer (score 5):

Fish can only be fed to your pet. http://www.runicfollower.com/wiki/torchlight/Fish

Answer (score 2):

The [Wiki at wikia](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Fish) states it as followed:

> Fish are consumable items for pets, acquired through trading and fishing. Fish may temporarily transform your pet into a monster, permanently transform your pet into another type of pet, or give it straight boosts to specific properties for a limited period of time. **Fish may also contain items of any rarity (all the way up to Unique) and consumables for the player.**

At the bottom of the page there also is a list of [Player Consumable Fish](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Fish#Player_consumables)

As stated by C Ross in his comment, this type of "fish" shows up in the equipment tab and is consumed via simple Right-click:

[image]